# How to grey out other radio buttons after one is selected until refresh

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

Hopefully somebody can prompt me into the right direction, 
I want a simple 3 radio button form, lets say 1,2,3
once 1 has been selected i want to disable options 2 and 3 until page has been refreshed
so maybe those option would grey out and not be selectable

any help appreciated cant find a thing on google

Comment: jQuery("#radiobutonID input:radio").attr('disabled',true);

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, **jQuery way**:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="1"> 1
  <input type="radio" value="2"> 2
  <input type="radio" value="3"> 3
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input:not(:checked)').attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
  })
</script>
```

To add jQuery to your project - simply insert

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

inside your `<head> </head>` tag.

**UPDATE:**
To keep it after page refreshes you should modify your code to this:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="1" id="radio1"> 1
  <input type="radio" value="2" id="radio2"> 2
  <input type="radio" value="3" id="radio3"> 3
</form>
<script>
  $('#'+localStorage.selected).trigger('click');
  $('#'+localStorage.selected).parent().find('input:not(:checked)').attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input:not(:checked)').attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
    localStorage.setItem('selected', $(this).attr('id'));
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Be careful there's no jquery tag in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

We will group radio buttons in a div:

```
<div class="readioBtnDiv">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" />1
</div>
<div class="readioBtnDiv">
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="1" />2
</div>
<div class="readioBtnDiv">
    <input type="radio" name="group3" value="1" />3
</div>
```

Now we will disable another radio button when one is selected:

```
$("input:radio").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();
    $this.closest('.readioBtnDiv') 
        .siblings('.readioBtnDiv') 
        .find('input:radio[value="' + value + '"]') 
        .attr("disabled","disabled"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think all the answers are right and accurate to your question above but according to me you would find this answer more useful and understandable if you are newbie**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("radio2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("radio3").disabled = true;
    }
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("radio1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("radio3").disabled = true;
    }
    function myFunction3() {
        document.getElementById("radio2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("radio1").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">
<input onclick="myFunction1();" type="radio" id="radio1" value="Radio1" /><label>Radio1</label>
<input onclick="myFunction2();" type="radio" id="radio2" value="Radio2" /><label>Radio2</label>
<input onclick="myFunction3();" type="radio" id="radio3" value="radio3" /><label>radio3</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**It's a working example according to your need. Cheers :)**

Comment: bottom answer works great is there a way to keep it after refresh?

Comment: You go for **localStorage**. But i think it's more useful that retaining state of page and controls using technology @ backend you're using. :) (example : view state, session, cookies)